# google maps v3 marker clustering without use of markerClusterer plugin or fusion or KML layers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, drag, markerclusterer

Yes, I did research here and found so far only references to the MarkerClusterer plugin, or pointers to using KML or Fusion table layers.

This: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markermanager
was also an interesting read.

I'm thinking this should be relatively easy, no? Let me try to express what I'm doing in pseudo-code:

```
WILE event: "drag the map"
  get current viewport bounds
  load ajax call to look up markers that are located inside current viewport
  remove previously visible markers
  add newly visible markers to the display
END WHILE
```

I'm not that great at proper computer-science programming type stuff and struggle with the necessary structure for performing an efficient loopable action like this that continuously updates the marker array.

Somehow my gut feeling tells me this might be an inefficient way - should I approach this differently? What I'd like to avoid is updating the marker array on drag end.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling and further searching, the solution is buried here: [google maps v3 duplicate markers - using an array to manage markers but still get duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641770/google-maps-v3-duplicate-markers-using-an-array-to-manage-markers-but-still-ge)