# google maps v3 duplicate markers - using an array to manage markers but still get duplicates

Tags: arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm not getting it: I have an array to manage my markers I add to a map. When I update the collection, the markers duplicate even though my markers array still only has the correct number of them in it.

I'm sure this is a really simple and stupid mistake on my part - but I'm not seeing it.

```
m.viewMarkers = function(data){
    //ajax call to get latLng, returns an object with 4 markers
    showMarkers();
}

function showMarkers(){
    g.currentMarkers = []; // setting up my marker array
    $.each(g.markersCollection, function(i,item){ // jquery-iterate over the object from the ajax call
        g.currentMarkers.push( // adding markers to the array but purposely not drawing them on the map just yet
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position    : new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng)
            });
        );
    });
$.each(g.currentMarkers, function(i,item){
    if( g.map.getBounds().contains( item.getPosition() ) ){ // checking if this marker is within the viewport
        item.setMap(g.map);
    }
    else {
        item.setMap(null); // i don't want to have invisible markers slowing down my map
    }
});
console.log(g.currentMarkers.length); // tells me it's 4, just as expected
}

google.maps.event.addListener(g.map, 'dragend', function() {
    m.viewMarkers();
});
```

To me this looks like all is well, but the map keeps drawing 4 new markers on every `dragend`.... eeek!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your `showMarkers()` function to this:

```
function showMarkers(){
    //Removing old markers from the Map,if they are exist
    if(g.currentMarkers && g.currentMarkers.length !== 0){            
        $.each(g.currentMarkers, function(i,item){
            item.setMap(null);
        });
    }
    g.currentMarkers = []; // setting up my marker array
    $.each(g.markersCollection, function(i,item){ 
           var expectedPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);
           //No need to add marker on the Map if it will not visible on viewport, 
           //so we check the position, before adding 
           if(g.map.getBounds().contains(expectedPosition)){
                g.currentMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    position : expectedPosition 
                }) );
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: And that's why you have 11k rep. Thanks. I figured out the duplication but your tip to check containment before adding vas really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: strangely, when checking for existing markers as you suggested, it will complain with a `TypeError` that `Object 0 has no method 'setMap'`. I think this is because it loops over `array.length+1` items, but why would it do that?

Comment: to comment on my own comment, I solved the problem by tracking 3 things: 1) the object array with my marker data, 2) an array of indexes of those objects whose position is contained within bounds and 3) an array of the actual markers I set on the map. phew! it seems overkill... but works. I use 1) for my bounds check, 2) as a reference and 3) to remove possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare new markers with your stored markers using some of following code (to display stored markers rather than new response marker):

```
var latlng1,latlng2;
for (var i=0; i< storedmarker.length; i++){
    //Removing old markers from the Map,if they are exist with storedmarkers
    latlng1 = storedmarker[i].getPosition();
    for (var j=0; j< newmarkers.length; j++) {
      latlng2 = newmarkers[j].getPosition();
      if(latlng1.equals(latlng2)){
        newmarkers[j].setMap(null);
      }
    }

    //Set Marker
    storedmarker[i].setMap(map);
}
```